# reload paypal button source depending on the image selected

Tags: html, css

I have 3 separate paypal buttons created. One for small, medium and large (all different prices)

the small, medium and large are images on my website S, M & L.

I want a customer to select S, M or L but these are all different prices so I want the 'add to cart' button to update automatically depending on what the customer selects. How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to use jQuery, this can be accomplished with ease.

First, include jquery with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Now use the code below. Give each image the ID of it's size (small, medium or large) and when that image is clicked the correct form will show. Remember to  paste the correct form fields into the correct spaces.

```
<script>    
    $('#small').click(function(){
        $('.paypalForm').hide();
        $('#smallForm').show();
    });
    $('#medium').click(function(){
        $('.paypalForm').hide();
        $('#mediumForm').show();
    });
    $('#large').click(function(){
        $('.paypalForm').hide();
        $('#largeForm').show();
    });
</script>

<form id="smallForm" class="paypalForm" target="paypal" action="paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    ...
</form>


<form id="mediumForm" class="paypalForm" target="paypal" action="paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    ...
</form>


<form id="largeForm" class="paypalForm" target="paypal" action="paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. basically what i want to do is for them to select e.g small (which it then highlights). Then the 'buy it now' button would change to the code for small so that when it is clicked it goes to paypal checkout for the small.

Comment: <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KZQPGPG7WQ3YY">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

Comment: quick question before i complete the code: where are you inputting the values of the links where the button will take you to?

Comment: the code i inserted above is the paypal button for small. There are another 2 for medium and large. im not sure of what you are asking? The only difference between each link is the value. e.g small is KZQPGPG7WQ3YY, medium is XJUPGPG7WQ5TY ETC.

Comment: please see link: http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/8991/72920293.jpg as an example

Comment: ahhh ok, i thought you were using one form that was going to have it's value change dynamically. i get what you want now, will post code in a minute.

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much, works a treat. As an addition would it be possible to add in a colour, liek so:http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/6838/ex2i.jpg. so now there are  6 different outcomes (6 different paypal links) i.e blue colour - small size, blue colour - medium size etc.

Comment: would be 9 options and yea it's possible, would just require more conditional statements. it will actually be easier to use a paypal dynamic button, which will definitely reduce the amount of forms on the page and make it all much more cleaner and manageable. You can read about them here:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

let me know if you wanna use that method.

Comment: whichever you think is easiest. Less code is better i guess. Thanks for your help on this project. where you have put <form id="smallForm" class="paypalForm" target="paypal" action="paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> etc how does paypal know which link button it is?

Comment: what happens is the link sends dynamic info which contains the price and item description. i'm assuming the colour doesn't actually affect the price of the size, ie a blue large costs the same as a red large?

Comment: yes thats correct however I want it to show up on paypal that they are ordering red large so I have to make a button for every event if you know what i mean

Comment: nah you don't need individual buttons, data is dynamic so it will change depending on their selection and then submit to paypal where it will say what they are buying.

Comment: refering to the link you sent: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside. can i use the very bottom form and change the radio buttons to images. Now I am unsure how to add the 'size' in. Can you help. if you can update this fiddle it owuld be good. http://jsfiddle.net/aGEhU/

Comment: yea i'm just busy doing something. when i'm done i'll write out the whole code for you to modify as you please.

Comment: the code above automatically goes to paypal checkout if an image is clicked, which is not what im looking for. I want the user to select image whether it be S,M or L then click a 'buy it now' button which will take them to paypal.